# Firebase authentication in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, firebase, asp.net-core, .net-core, firebase-authentication

How do you implement Firebase authentication and user management in .Net Core 2.0?

I am using the JWT Token created and returned by Google Firebase but wondering what would be the best practice to authenticate users in ASP .Net Core framework.

Do you create an Identity User and related classes using the ASP .Net [Identity membership system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)? Or do you manage access completely relying on ClaimsIdentity passed by Firebase?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Cookie Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#configuration) provided by ASP NET Core.'

1. Use [Firebase API](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet) to log-in
2. If that is successful, add claims (if you need to), and then use the HttpContext.SignInAsync(...) method to sign in.

Comment: But if I am using JWT Token
(services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme))
 and the user is already authenticated, so I am confused, should I still implement HttpContext.SignInAsync(...)?

Comment: Yes, you are authenticated in the eyes of Google (Firebase), but not in the eyes of your ASP NET Core website, thus you need to add the cookie authentication layer. Any more questions, message me or comment!

Comment: WOW, this is exactly what I have been looking for. This has helped me so much to combine Firebase Authentication but still use ASP NET Core cookies on the website from page to page. Works really well. I wanted a solution where I was not storing the email/passwords for each user in my own DB but could offload that responsibility to another provider e.g. Firebase but still provide the ASP NET Core cookie authentication once auth'd by Firebase login. :-)